# Python function gets stuck (no error) but I can't understand why

Tags: python, python-3.x

The function does what I want it to, but when it's done it just sits there rather than continuing from where I called it and I can't figure out why. The code is:

```
x = 9
y = 9
n = 10
ty = 1
tx = 1

while ty <= y:
    while tx <= x:
        vars()["p" + str(ty) + str(tx)] = 0
        tx += 1
    ty += 1
    tx = 1

tn = 1
while tn <= n:
    vars()["m" + str(tn)] = tn
    tn += 1

t = x * y
tm = n
def recursion(z):
    global tm
    if z < n:
        for x in range(n):
            recursion(z + 1)
    else:
        if tm > 0:
            tv = "m" + str(tm)
            otm = eval(tv)
            while eval(tv) < t - n + tm:
                vars()[tv] = eval(tv) + 1
                print(tv + " = " + str(eval(tv)))
            vars()[tv] = otm + 1
            print(tv + " = " + str(eval(tv)))
            if tm > 1:
                vars()["m" + str(tm - 1)] = eval("m" + str(tm - 1)) + 1
                print(str("m" + str(tm - 1) + " = " + str(eval("m" + str(tm -1)))))
            tm -= 1

recursion(1)

print("done")
```

I've put the return in where I would expect it to end but as far as I know it shouldn't actually need it.

Can anyone see what I've done to cause it to get stuck?

Thanks

Comment: If it gets stuck, it doesnt do what you want. Every recursion needs a base case, where it returns a basic value, and a recursive part where the actual function call is made in a return statement. Your function doesn't do so.

(return recursion(z+1) )

Comment: Where is `n` defined?

Comment: @dg99: And `t`, and `m1`, and `m2`... This code is madness! It looks like an entry to the POCC (Python Obfuscation Code Contest).

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by base case but thanks, I now have some keywords I can use to try to learn. I only included where I define the function and then call it. Didn't think the rest would be relevant.

Comment: This is not working code, please edit it to contain the definitions of your variables. Why have you chosen to use if/else instead of while?

Comment: I've added the rest of the code. This is my first attempt at recursion, I used if/else because that was what I found when looking up how to do it.

Comment: You seem to be making a ridiculously, exponentially huge number of recursive calls.

Comment: should this be on code review?

Comment: It is a bit silly (my test 9x9, n=10 generated over 25,000 states and I plan to up those numbers significantly), but I'm just playing around trying to learn so won't mind if it takes a few minutes to run each time. On top of all that, the solution I came up with below is still missing some so the actual amount of states should be even higher.

Comment: It's going to take a lot longer than just a few minutes if you keep upping the dimensions. Have you given any thought to what your recursive calls do after `tm` hits 0? Also, all that use of `eval` and `vars` is a horrible way to do whatever you're trying to do. You should be creating lists and dicts and indexing those instead of using `eval` and `vars`, especially since `vars` doesn't actually work the way you think it does - changes to `vars` are quite likely to just vanish or be ignored.

Comment: At the moment I'm just trying to figure out how to create the foundations for what I'm trying to do. My plan is to replace all the prints with appending to a list and then use that data to work some stuff out. I have read that dicts are better than variables for stuff like this but I don't really know why and it seems to be working as it is (again, emphasise my answer below, not the broken code above).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note for people not going through the change history: This is based on the comments on other answers. UPDATE: Better version.

```
import itertools

def permutations(on, total):
    all_indices = range(total)
    for indices in itertools.combinations(all_indices, on):
        board = ['0'] * total
        for index in indices:
            board[index] = '1'
        yield ''.join(board)
```

Comment: That is incredibly faster than the code I came up with and a lot simpler and easy to read too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to work out what was happening (turns out if I left it for a few minutes it would actually finish though), instead, I realised that I didn't need to use recursion to achieve what I wanted (and I also realised the function didn't actually do what I want to do).

For anyone interested, I simplified and rewrote it to be a few while loops instead:

```
x = 9
y = 9
t = x * y
n = 10

tt = 1
while tt <= t:
        vars()["p" + str(tt)] = 0
        tt += 1

tn = 1
while tn <= n:
    vars()["m" + str(tn)] = tn
    vars()["p" + str(tn)] = 1
    tn += 1

def cl():
    w = ""
    tt = 1
    while tt <= t:
        w = w + str(eval("p" + str(tt)))
        tt += 1
    p.append(w)

tm = n
tv = "m" + str(tm)
p = []
while m1 < t - n + tm - 1:    
    cl()
    while tm == n and eval(tv) < t - n + tm:
        vars()["p" + str(eval(tv))] = 0
        vars()[tv] = eval(tv) + 1
        vars()["p" + str(eval(tv))] = 1
        cl()        
    tm -= 1
    tv = "m" + str(tm)
    while tm < n and tm > 0:
        if eval(tv) < t - n + tm:
            vars()["p" + str(eval(tv))] = 0
            vars()[tv] = eval(tv) + 1
            vars()["p" + str(eval(tv))] = 1
            while tm < n:
                tm += 1
                ptv = tv
                tv = "m" + str(tm)
                vars()["p" + str(eval(tv))] = 0
                vars()[tv] = eval(ptv) + 1
                vars()["p" + str(eval(tv))] = 1
        else:
            tm -= 1
            tv = "m" + str(tm)
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this code supposed to do? It looks like an infinite loop when I try to run it (once I resolve the name errors).

Comment: I think that version I posted might be to be honest, I carried on struggling with it for ages. It was supposed to generate every possible state a grid of x by y could be in with n amount of 1s, the rest 0. I later realised I was just outputting it as a single line so massively simplified it, I will update post with it now since you're interested.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is interested in what the original code did, I rearranged the conditionals to prune the tree of function calls:

```
x = 9
y = 9
n = 10
ty = 1
tx = 1

while ty <= y:
    while tx <= x:
        vars()["p" + str(ty) + str(tx)] = 0
        tx += 1
    ty += 1
    tx = 1

tn = 1
while tn <= n:
    vars()["m" + str(tn)] = tn
    tn += 1

t = x * y
tm = n
def recursion(z):
    global tm
    if tm > 0:
        if z < n:
            for x in range(n):
                recursion(z + 1)
        else:
            tv = "m" + str(tm)
            otm = eval(tv)
            while eval(tv) < t - n + tm:
                vars()[tv] = eval(tv) + 1
                print(tv + " = " + str(eval(tv)))
            vars()[tv] = otm + 1
            print(tv + " = " + str(eval(tv)))
            if tm > 1:
                vars()["m" + str(tm - 1)] = eval("m" + str(tm - 1)) + 1
                print(str("m" + str(tm - 1) + " = " + str(eval("m" + str(tm -1)))))
            tm -= 1

recursion(1)

print("done")
```

This could be made much clearer through the use of lists and range objects, but that takes effort.